# Laravel / Lumen $users = \App\User::find$Uid)->get();

Tags: laravel, lumen, paginator

normally i use this:

```
$users = \App\Users::where('age', '>=', '20')->paginate(20);
```

But if I use raw querys or use the `get();` method from `querybuilder`, I got an array not a collection or a paginator instance as result.

How can I get my `->links();` from that array result?
Hope all is explained well. :-)

KR,
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Write`{{ $users->links() }}` in your view page. According to your query, pagination will show while your data return more than 20 rows.

For better understand [Read this doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: I use the twig template engine not blade, so what can I use there? There is no {% links() %} ??? 

I use twigbridge -> https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge to get my twig templates running in my lumen app.

Comment: So, Mention TwigBridge in the description of your question. You may get a quick reply from the TwigBridge expert people.